# Sonarqube rule deactivation is not working

Tags: php, sonarqube, rule

I want to deactivate a particular rule. I am checking my php code.

> E.g.: This branch's code block is the same as the block for the branch
>   This is the rule I deactivate

I go  through quality profile-->then click to the php sonar way -->then click on 64 active rules->then I deactivate that rule.  Then I logout and login the same bug is visible in the dashboard.. what should I do? How to deactivate the rule ? Is there any another method ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should run analysis again with an updated quality profile.